# @font-face - Fonts Not Requested by Browser, Not Loading

Tags: css, fonts, shopify, font-face

I'm attempting to load 4 fonts using `@font-face` as critical styles in the header for above-the-fold content, within `<style>` tags.

- Rubik-Bold
- Rubik-Italic
- Rubik-LightItalic
- Rubik-Regular

From what I can tell this should be correct, however only the first in the list loads.  If I removed the first one, the next-in-line will be the first to load.

HTML:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Bold.eot?2568338257603816725');
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Bold.eot?2568338257603816725#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Bold.woff?2568338257603816725') format("woff"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Bold.woff2?2568338257603816725') format("woff2"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Bold.ttf?2568338257603816725') format("truetype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Bold.svg?2568338257603816725#timber-icons') format("svg");
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
};

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Italic.eot?2568338257603816725');
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Italic.eot?2568338257603816725#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Italic.woff?2568338257603816725') format("woff"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Italic.woff2?2568338257603816725') format("woff2"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Italic.ttf?2568338257603816725') format("truetype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Italic.svg?2568338257603816725#timber-icons') format("svg"); 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
};

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-LightItalic.eot?2568338257603816725');
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-LightItalic.eot?2568338257603816725#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-LightItalic.woff?2568338257603816725') format("woff"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-LightItalic.woff2?2568338257603816725') format("woff2"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-LightItalic.ttf?2568338257603816725') format("truetype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-LightItalic.svg?2568338257603816725#timber-icons') format("svg");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
};

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rubik'; 
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Regular.eot?2568338257603816725');
    src: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Regular.eot?2568338257603816725#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Regular.woff?2568338257603816725') format("woff"),
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Regular.woff2?2568338257603816725') format("woff2"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Regular.ttf?2568338257603816725') format("truetype"), 
        url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1735/6971/t/25/assets/Rubik-Regular.svg?2568338257603816725#timber-icons') format("svg"); 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
};
```

This is what I get in Chrome's inspector:

Things I've tried based on similar threads I've read:

1. Eliminated all whitespace and put each `@font-face` on one line (solved the issue in another thread).
2. Tested the links that Shopify's CDN outputs, and they do work.

On the page, in the header:

HTML:

```
<div class="gift-line show-for-large">
    <span>The Gift Line</span><span class="phone-number">XXX-XXX-XXXX</span>
</div>
```

And CSS, loaded before the font-face declarations (span should be inheriting this rule and therefore Rubik-Regular should be downloading):

```
body {
    font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

So in this case, I know that at least Rubik-Regular should be called in addition to Rubik-Bold. (There are no

Any suggestions?  Thanks

[image]

Comment: You're calling them two of them the same, (italic). change that and make sure the font is referenced in your CSS that is active on the page. The browsers try to minimize http requests like that by only loading what is needed.

Comment: Thanks Dominik, does it matter than although they are both italic, the `font-weight` is different?  Also, I know for a fact that `Rubik-Regular` should be loading.

Comment: share your html and we have a look and yes you would have to use each combination

Comment: Sure thing, I'm updating the description now.  It's Liquid logic that produces the HTML you see posted above.

Comment: No we need the html and css of that page to see if the font is actually called :)

Comment: :P. Thanks.  I added more context at the bottom of the question, so Rubik-Regular is being called as a critical style before the font declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers try to minimize network connections by analizing your css and html to determine what font files you end up using and only download those.

Since you're using the same `font-family` name here you have to make sure you use each style combination of `font-weight` and `font-style` on the page for the browser to download all of them.

Also don't be tricked by some of the caching smarts browser put into place. Font's are cached quickly to prevent http requests.

I suggest you ignore the network traffic and inspect your element that is supposed to get the font and look at the `computed` tab.

For more information around how to debug fonts have a look at this short [article by Paul Irish](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that).

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, I know that the combination of `font-family: 'Rubik'`, `font-weight: normal`, and `font-style: normal` are being used, however Rubik-Regular isn't requested by any of the major browsers.

Comment: Added more infos on how to debug your font loading